# tmap::tm_facets() in interactive mode in html R Markdown file, small multiples variable title renders in wrong place

Tags: r

If you look at this reproducible snippet, when knitting, the first small multiples set renders both its and the next small multiples' title variable in the first set of maps.

[image]

Here's the reproducible example:

````
---
title: "TEST"
author: "author"
output: 
  html_document
---

```{r}

library("tmap")
library("tmaptools")

tmap_mode("view")
data(World)

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_fill("pop_est", thres.poly = 0) +
  tm_facets("name", free.coords=TRUE, drop.units=TRUE) +
  tm_layout(panel.label.size = 2, legend.show = FALSE)




tm_shape(World) +
  tm_fill("pop_est", thres.poly = 0, palette = "BuGn") +
  tm_facets("name", free.coords=TRUE, drop.units=TRUE) +
  tm_layout(panel.label.size = 2, legend.show = FALSE)


```
````

As you can see, the first set of multiples show the country names twice, whereas they're not rendered in the second set at all. This is showing itself in a more complicated report I'm working on elsewhere, but this is reproducible using nothing but tmap data and functions.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This works correctly for me - I see one country name on each facet plot on both web pages. tmap version 1.10. I'm running from the R console and viewing the map in two web browser tabs. Is it because you are viewing both in one? If you are viewing this from a markdown doc you should give the code you are using to render the markdown to HTML.

Comment: Problem confirmed when rendered using `rmarkdown::render("maps.Rmd")` and viewing the HTML in a web browser. Its a bug. Not sure what in though...

Comment: It also does this if you put the two `tm_shape` calls in two chunks separated by some text. It also doesn't matter if you fill on a different variable or facet by another variable - if you do three plots with different fills and facets you get three labels on the first and no labels on the second and third...